# Vector layer invisible; attribute table empty but large shp and db files exist

Tags: qgis, shapefile

Systems being used: QGIS 2.8.6. on Linux Ubuntu and also on Mac Sierra.

I have been sent a large shp file 13.4MB and dbf file 3.4MB plus the other 6 files for the shapefile vector layer (all probably created in ArcGIS). All these files are held together in the same folder and their names are Hcc_cropmarks.shp etc.

This data represents archaeological features seen in aerial photographs and the shape file should contain a very large number of 'line' features varying in size from tens of meters to several kilometers long. The owner of this data is not apparently having any problem seeing it themselves in their ArcGIS system and previous shp files they have supplied worked perfectly for me.

I used 'add vector layer' to add the shp layer to an existing project. It is the topmost layer and is invisible even if all the other layers are turned off. I used CRS EPSG:27700 OSGB1936/British National Grid) which is the same as my project.

I believe that this is the correct CRS/projection as opening the prj file with gedit shows the following:

`PROJCS["OSGB 1936 / British National Grid",GEOGCS["OSGB 1936",DATUM["OSGB_1936",SPHEROID["Airy 1830",6377563.396,299.3249646,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7001"]],TOWGS84[446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6277"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4277"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",49],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-2],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996012717],PARAMETER["false_easting",400000],PARAMETER["false_northing",-100000],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","27700"]]`

**My problem is that the layer is invisible**. 'Zoom to layer' causes a zoom out for the other layers in my working area (but they are still visible) but the cropmark layer is invisible.  I can open the dbf with Libre Office on the Mac (but not on the Linux box which gives error message "General error. General input/output error.). The data in the dbf is arranged as a table of 3 columns (headers are OBJECTID,N,10,0; CROPMAR_ID,N,10,0; Shape_STLe,N,19,11) and about 100,000 rows, sequentially numbered in the first column.

When I open the attribute table for the layer it shows the 3 headers (without the N,10,0 etc) but no other data - the table is otherwise apparently empty.

The layer does not appear to be making the connection between shp and dbf.

I need to know if the visibility problem is of my making or whether the data I have been sent is incomplete/corrupted, in which case I could go back to the creator and ask for a fresh copy - but obviously  I don't want to trouble them if it is my error.

Any suggestions for making the layer visible?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Can edit your question and provide the layer name and where you obtained it from (download url)?

Comment: At a minimum, you need to re-transfer the data, paying close attention to file sizes in transit.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing everything correctly, but that your data is corrupt. Get the data owner to send you a new copy of the data.